# Why do vectors disappears when zooming in?

Tags: qgis, vector, gpx

I have imported a .gpx file into qgis and separated the track waypoints using Vector > GPS > GPS tools.  When viewing at full extent I can see the original track and component waypoints.  However when I zoom in, the track lines disappear but the waypoints are still there. I have tried:

- checking track layer scale dependent rendering is OFF
- exporting track layer as .shp and adding to map
- moving track layer to top of layer stack
- toggling map rendering

but still cannot view track when zooming in.  Any ideas?
Thanks,

Tony

[EDIT] I have uploaded Pic1 which shows zoomed to the layer extent ('GPX tracklog export').  Pic2 is when it has zoomed in with mouse wheel and part of the shapefile has diappeared. Note these are the gpx file tracklog exported as a shapefile.

[image: Pic1 - at image extent]

[image: Pic2 - zoom in]

Comment: For a shapefile, sometimes the .sbn and .sbx files cause this behavior (which you may delete).

Comment: I experience the same problem with a vector shapefile sent to me from the British Oceanography Data Centre (so I assume it shouldn't have too many faults? Not necessarily true). Looks fine when zoomed to layer full extent, disappears completely when I zoom in. I'll raise this as a bug @ hub.qgis.org. Please comment if you've had the same experience.

Comment: I have the same problem with data recorded with a garmin gps, whole track disapears when zooming in.

Comment: Or a .qix file in my case

Answer (score 2):

Does it help to insert points into the way geometry?

Sometimes ways don't get rendered if all points of the way are outside the current window.

[EDIT 2] from user19425
I can't seem to add a separate comment, possibly because this is a closed question.  But anyway thanks Joost, that worked.  Are you aware if this is a tracked bug?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that QGIS shows this behaviour when coming across invalid or "dirty" geometries in your layer. Unfortunately, no specific warning/error log messages are generated. Similar effects have been reported in an [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28211) where users suggest to validate the layer geometry accordingly and to

> clean it using processing v.clean tool.

In general GRASS GIS offers a powerful toolset for vector cleaning which can be partly used in QGIS through the GRASS plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a .qix file worked for me